# "mailto:" doesn't set complete email address

Tags: html

I'm trying to set up a mailto: link to send an email to an address structured like "name.surname@mycompany.com"
I'm trying to use the classic
`<a href="mailto:name.surname@mycompany.com">click here!</a>`
but once the default emailing app opens up, the recipient slot is missing the "@mycompany.com" part of the address.

I have been searching online for the past 2 hours without much success. I have also tried using character encoding to "force" the @ symbol to somehow come out but I still haven't come up with any solution.

Comment: Maybe it's a browser-specific bug, what browser did you test this on?

Answer (score 1):

You can design a button so use form and enctype when user click them submit in your email
`<form method="post" action="mailto:name.surname@mycompany.com" enctype="text/plain"></form>`

or add attribute `target="_blank"`